# ARIMA model gave me 99% difference between the forecast values and the true values

Tags: time-series, forecasting, arima

I am new to ARIMA model. I try to fit the `arima` model to the data and find the forecasting values. Then, compare the predicted values to the true ones. I fit the `arima` model and forecast from it. However, when I compare the forecasted values with the true values, I found that the difference between them is 99%. So, the fitted model is so bad. I am confused where is it my problem, or mistake?

Here is what I tried and my data:

```r
    datlogPrice <- diff(log(Price[1:200])) # My training data
    plot(datlogPrice)
    fit1<- auto.arima(datlogPrice)
    summary(fit1)
    Box.test(resid(fit1), lag=45, type="Ljung-Box")
   fcast<-forecast(fit1, h=70
   plot(fcast, main="")
    Values<-as.numeric(fcast$mean)
    Finalvalues<-exp(Values)
   dat <- as.numeric(Price[201:270]) # This is the real data to compare with the forecasted one. 

    errors<-round((dat-Finalvalues)/dat,4)*100
    df<-data.frame(dat, Finalvalues, errors)
    colheadings<-c("Actual Price", "Forecasted Price", "Forecast Error (%)")
    names(df)<-colheadings
    attach(df)
    view(df)
```

My data

```r
     structure(list(Price = c(7213.03, 7288.81, 7285.23, 7222.41, 
    7207.78, 7267.86, 7300.48, 7329.38, 7328.09, 7309.8, 7292.54, 
    7263.65, 7308.21, 7309.67, 7355.66, 7345.88, 7260.09, 7265.08, 
    7213.36, 7232.34, 7292.62, 7287.41, 7224.09, 7253.33, 7312.24, 
    7388.49, 7390.59, 7400.53, 7394.26, 7416.67, 7431.58, 7412.21, 
    7380.35, 7426.76, 7426.76, 7306.64, 7377.36, 7417.26, 7427.89, 
    7426.78, 7434.05, 7455.74, 7459.21, 7470.26, 7499.97, 7530.31, 
    7535.96, 7626.23, 7645.55, 7704.25, 7759.48, 7757.26, 7853.57, 
    7853.05, 7842.84, 7901.93, 7957.38, 7938.36, 7955.04, 7934.43, 
    7983.82, 7940.7, 7898.86, 8013.44, 8045.09, 8024.62, 8050.14, 
    8089.54, 8079.74, 8135.16, 8203.57, 8256.07, 8321.74, 8311.21, 
    8337.88, 8364.61, 8291.35, 8244.82, 8236.17, 8293.62, 8334.65, 
    8284.34, 8299.08, 8295.05, 8177.76, 8257.67, 8369.33, 8358.79, 
    8412.55, 8513.26, 8544.94, 8601.07, 8592.1, 8553.79, 8560.81, 
    8547.61, 8533, 8496.85, 8505.18, 8154.59, 8155.31, 8198.9, 8123.05, 
    7907.72, 7864.78, 8021.02, 7998.59, 8088.73, 8089.15, 8160.35, 
    8366.46, 8405.04, 8449.66, 8434.9, 8501.58, 8526.64, 8572.73, 
    8621.19, 8578.42, 8588.17, 8610.84, 8636.14, 8688.76, 8693.47, 
    8708.59, 8747.09, 8722.12, 8694.13, 8674.97, 8581.68, 8633.38, 
    8612.13, 8660.21, 8643.97, 8644.47, 8660.31, 8659.37, 8721.18, 
    8711.58, 8686.89, 8538.68, 8680.45, 8720.67, 8702.68, 8740.66, 
    8715.38, 8746.76, 8760.08, 8689.53, 8612.82, 8667.66, 8682.11, 
    8670.8, 8737.2, 8817.05, 8869.47, 8884.46, 8914.29, 8898.68, 
    8874.9, 8931.29, 8901.87, 8878.3, 8876.49, 8829.52, 8846.95, 
    8789.87, 8784.12, 8807.02, 8702.55, 8648.43, 8618.57, 8542.55, 
    8617.87, 8687.93, 8809.34, 8892.92, 8901.63, 8943.85, 9035.53, 
    9081.78, 9101.96, 9084.31, 9024.23, 9085.97, 9077.62, 9151.71, 
    9115.76, 9194.92, 9144.99, 9138.37, 9248.28, 9310.28, 9242.28, 
    9351.08, 9374.37, 9473.2, 9595.45, 9587.79, 9664.61, 9645.74, 
    9660.27, 9602.26, 9485.96, 9498.85, 9547.42, 9489.63, 9464.08, 
    9417.71, 9482.95, 9615.63, 9635.34, 9907.82, 9895.56, 9962.77, 
    9964.84, 9988.98, 10014.3, 10012.13, 9938.32, 9907.62, 9838.28, 
    9847.62, 9987.92, 10048.7, 10097.65, 10116.98, 10095.36, 10134.08, 
    10142.48, 10231.06, 10267.17, 10531.22, 10418.98, 10365.51, 10309.37, 
    10318.94, 10252.15, 10228.35, 10228.19, 10322.68, 10396.44, 10423.51, 
    10372.54, 10339.85, 10343.86, 10318.51, 10448, 10471.55, 10519.52, 
    10547.67, 10551.23, 10597.42, 10656.81, 10698.3, 10685.45, 10719.85, 
    10735.39, 10790.24, 10796.33, 10897.47, 10913.56, 10831.38, 10855.95, 
    10853.12, 10790.75, 10859.18, 10891.64, 10894.2, 10919.68)), row.names = c(NA, 
    -270L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is that your code doesn't correctly invert the transformation. It starts by transforming prices into log-returns:

$$r_t := \Delta \log{P_t}$$

Then, it fits an ARIMA model to $r_t$, which gives you the forecasts $\hat{r}_{T+1|T}$, ..., $\hat{r}_{T+h|T}$, but you ultimately want forecasts for the prices, so you have to invert this transformation. Your code then does this:

$$\hat{P}_{T+h|T} = e^{\hat{r}_{T+h|T}}$$

This gives you a price in the neighborhood of 1 dollar instead of the 10k it should be, hence the "99.99% difference". The usual way to infer forecasts for prices from forecasts for returns is this:

$$\hat{P}_{T+1|T} = P_Te^{\hat{r}_{T+1|T}}$$
$$\hat{P}_{T+2|T} = P_Te^{\hat{r}_{T+1|T}+\hat{r}_{T+2|T}}$$
$$...$$
$$\hat{P}_{T+h|T} = P_Te^{\sum_{i=1}^h \hat{r}_{T+i|T}}$$

That is, you have to cumulate the impact of forecasted returns on the last observed price level.

You could also not transform the prices in advance and set `lambda = 0` in `forecast::auto.arima`, and it will fit the model on the transformed scale but return forecasts on the untransformed (price) scale. Although, it may or may not always decide to include a difference in the model, but for this data it does.